# Error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'" in phpmyadmin when trying to INSERT INTO an empty table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, insert

I have 2 tables in the same DB in phpmyadmin. Table 'csv' is where I imported data in order to clean it and format it. 'client' is a table/back-end connected to my forms UI. I am trying to INSERT selected columns from 'csv' INTO 'client'. I have checked that they are both in MyISAM format. And I am not including any PK columns. The 'client' table has a PK column that is generated by my front-end code. But I cleared that table of any test data so there can't be any duplicates.

Here is the sql I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO client 
(`first_name`, `last_name`, `street_address`, `city`, `zipcode`, `cell`) 
SELECT `CSVFirst` as `first_name`,`CSVLast` as `last_name`, `CSVAddress` as `street_address`, `CSVCity` as `city`, `CSVZip` as `zipcode`, `CSVPhone` as `cell`
FROM csv
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's obvious that a primary key value is repeated So  what is your Primary key and how the values generated and inserted on it?

Comment: thanks Nefazodone, the target table 'client' has a PK called `client_id` with unique ids. not repeated. No matter what I try to insert it still gives me the same error. No matter if I do an INSERT INTO SELECT or just a plain INSERT with a single value. for example: ''' INSERT INTO client(`day`)
SELECT `CSVday` AS `day`
FROM csv; '''  gives me the same error as ''' INSERT INTO client(day)
VALUE ('Tuesday'); '''      There only one primary key column and it is definitely unique.

Comment: and sorry I didn't answer your question, the PK values were generated with the UUID() function.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed an UPDATE not an INSERT. The Duplicate key message was because when INSERTing, it tries to add rows after the last existing row. which all have NULL pk values, hence the duplictae. So to add rows into an existing set of rows, use UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table2
```

JOIN table1 ON
table2.`first_name`= table1.`table1First`
AND table2.`street_address` = table1.`table1Address`
AND table2.`cell` = table1.`table1Phone`
SET `day` = `table1day` WHERE 1

Answer (score 0):

Try `INSERT IGNORE INTO` read more about it here [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm#:~:text=Use%20the%20INSERT%20IGNORE%20command,silently%20without%20generating%20an%20error](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20INSERT%20IGNORE%20command,silently%20without%20generating%20an%20error).